# Buffered/batch serialization in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, serialization, pickle

I have an algorithm that iteratively creates a very large, highly nested dictionary. I would like to buffer parts of this dictionary and then periodically stream the buffer to disk so that I can re-create the whole dictionary at another time.

It seems like pickle is intended for one-pass serialization. Is there a way to serialize a dictionary in batches to a single output stream?

Comment: `klepto` is capable of serializing one dictionary entry at a time to pass entries between database-like objects (such as a SQL db, a bunch of files, etc). `klepto` provides an easy way to pass dictionary entries between distributed/parallel resources.  Is this what you mean?

Comment: @MikeMcKerns thanks. My goals are a little simpler. I just don't want to waste time with RAM management while the algorithm runs. However, I want to reconstruct the entire dictionary in RAM later. Its really just for speed purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it looks like the following will partially solve the problem:

```
with open('file','ab') as f:
  while <stopping condition>:
    <generate (key,value) pair 'k'>
    pickle.dump(k,f)
```

Now, to reconstruct the whole dictionary, you just do the following:

```
with open('file','rb') as f:
    fullMapping = {}
        hasNext = True
        while hasNext:
            try:
                fullMapping.update(pickle.load(f))
            except:
                f.close()
                hasNext = False
```

This will reconstitute the full dictionary when run.